# Explanation of the Leibniz formula

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am reading the book Solving Ordinary Differential Equations I - Nonstiff Problems (1987) by Hairer et al. My question is from Section II, chapter 2 (Order conditions for RK methods), equation 2.4.

I am staring at a piece of text which goes like this:

> On the right hand side of (2.3) there appear expressions of the form
>   $\left(h\;\phi(h)\right)$, so we make use of Leibniz' formula
>
> $\left(h\;\phi(h)\right)^{(q)}|_{h = 0} = q.
>  \;\left(\phi(h)\right)^{(q - 1)}|_{h=0}$

I was wondering if someone could share some basic idea on the above.

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean the formula for higher derivatives?

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. I got hold of a page explaining that with your terms as search key.